# React hook form only allow numbers greater than 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I'm using React Hook Form to make an input for height, weight and length. The value cannot be 0 - it has to be at least 1 or more. I tried different ways such as: pattern with regex, validate and more. But I am unable to figure out how to prevent the input field from letting the user type in '0' ( only as the first character ). I also tried type="number" and min="1" however it's not changing anything. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
                    <Input
                      {...form.register(`pallets.${index}.weight`, {
                        required: t('errors.emptyInput'),
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[^1-9]/,
                          message: 'hello',
                        },
                        validate: (value) => {
                          return [/^[^1-9]/].every((pattern) => pattern.test(value))
                        },
                      })}
                      type='number'
                    />
```

It appears to me that `pattern` does not change anything. Only `type= 'number'` actually affects the way the input field works.

Answer (score 4):

```js
<input
  type="number"
  {...register("test", {
    min: 1
  })}
/>
```

You can check the detailed usage from the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/).

Comment: thank you for taking your time to answer my question - however I did indeed try this.. I don't know what's wrong with it, but I can still type in 0.. I also set ```max: 5``` and I can type in 125 or 50 for example

Comment: Ok, so you want to block users to write them to input which is not a validation. With this functionality when the user tries to submit, it throws an error. 

To fix your issue, you need to add a custom getter and setter to your input.

See the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-burnell-swi19e?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of react `useState` hook to implement this functionality.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(null);
  const handleChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    if (!value || /^[1-9]\d*/.test(value))
      setX(e.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" value={x} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Input type "number" is now discouraged, so the following rule works for text inputs:

```
{
    value: /^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$/,
    message: 'Input must be a number greater than 0.'
}
```

This also works with leading zeros, which is useful for human input.

Comment: why is it now discouraged?

Comment: https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/

Answer (score 0):

May be try something like this,code might need some syntax fixes

I was struggling with limiting user input to some specific value, `{ mode: 'onChange' }` worked for me

```
const { control } = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' });
<Controller
  control={control}
  name='inputName'
  rules={{
    min: {
      value: 1,
      message: 'Value must be between 1 and 100.',
    },
max: {
      value: 100,
      message: 'Value must be between 1 and 100.',
    },
  }}
  render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
      <Input
          type='number'
          controlId='input-id'
          value={field.value}
          onChange={event =>    field.onChange(event)}
        />
        {fieldState.error && <span>fieldState.error.message</span>}
  )}
/>
```